# python3, audio streaming

Tags: python-3.x, audio, streaming, latency

I'm trying to measure audio latency while streaming audio from RPI3 to a remote host. I need a Python program to measure the latency. I found this small script while searching and as the writer said it used to measure the delay!

Can anyone explain the function of the script, please?! Can I use it to measure the delay?

```
import time
import sys
while True:
  time.sleep(0.001)
  print('%s\r' % (int(time.time() * 1000) % 10000), end='')
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Just try the script yourself. Show us your code for the measuring the stream delay. You will have a large pile of work ahead to accomplish your task if you don't understand the above code, yet.

Comment: thank you for your replay. i know i have a larg pile of work to acomplish my work. but i just want someone clarifying the function of python program because i don not have any background on python programming..... thank you again